# Using for loop on nested object

Tags: ios, vue.js, nativescript

I've finnaly managed to start with nativescript and vuejs but I cannot seem to use for on listview with an object. The v-for on wallets works fine but the for on countries doesnt work if it is an object with multiple keys and values. What should be the correct way and code to make it work?  Where countries is the same object as wallets. It does work with an array but i want it to work with an object. (Only need the listview component)

```
    <flexbox-layout class="line">
        <label v-for="(wallet, index) in wallets" :text="wallet.name" ></label>
    </flexbox-layout>

    <ListView class="list-group" for="country in countries" @itemTap="onItemTap" style="height:1250px">
        <v-template>
            <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
                <Image :src="country.imageSrc" class="thumb img-circle" />
                <Label :text="country.name" class="list-group-item-heading" style="width: 60%" />
            </FlexboxLayout>
        </v-template>
    </ListView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView works quite differently from other components for better performance. It does not run a actual for loop here unlike v-for. Therefore it works only with Array so you will have to convert your object into an array before passing it to ListView.